# 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException', reason: 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-active-directory

We are authenticating the users using Azure active directory. However, we got the below error even after the user is authenticated successfully. The azure token etc. is generalted successfully.

> 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException', reason: 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: Authorization has been denied for this request

We have checked that user has all access levels need to access the application.
We are experiencing this error in mobile app which we have developed using xamarin on iOS platform.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Sounds like a missing scope. Check the token at e.g. https://jwt.ms.

Comment: @juunas Can you please add more details/steps etc. This issue is occured on production for some users

Comment: Right, might be a bit hard to grab one of the non-functioning tokens then. Azure AD always returns a mostly sensible error message, you might need to see if you can add some logging of that. Are you using some library?

Comment: @juunas not library, every settings we added in the code. Then using those settings It is going login.microsoftonline.com and then to our companys login portal

Comment: Where do you get this error? In the xamarin app?

Comment: Yes mean, we have written web api which authentcated the user

Comment: It would be good if you added the relevant code if available to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that the Api is returning some exception which is not handled at App side. I faced the same and the issue was that the Api was saving some data in DB but it was throwing foreign key constraints exception because of wrong data. But on Xamarin APP it showed the Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException. 
Pass some incorrect data from APP and check.